# Unable to upload files on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Following is the code which I'm using to upload file:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change permission of directory using command

```
chmod -R 777 <path>
```

if you want to change permission of subdirectories also

otherwise

```
chmod 777 <path>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It helped me. #Anto Livish A

Comment: No mention @Indrabhushan and dont forget to up vote and support :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct permission for file created path.  Simply you can set 777 file permission to the folder, But it is not the correct way to do. First you have to check the program running user & according that user you have to set the correct permission for that dir.

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not have the permission to be opened.
You can change it by doing.

```
chmod +rwx filename
```